# start node and pm2 application from bat file

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud, chatbot, pm2

I have a chat-bot application running on node and I keep it always active thanks to pm 2.

I would like to improve the way I launch the application. Instead of running the start command from the console, it would be nice to double click a .bat file.

I am trying to develop the bat file, but I lack knowledge.

I am grateful for any help.

```
@echo off
SET PM2_HOME=C:\Users\Usuario\.pm2
pm2 start C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\ROBOTs\Chatbot SCTR\app.js
echo servicio ejecutado
```

This bat file that I developed does not work. I know that I am not calling the variables, because I don't know how to include it, since I always execute the pm2 start app.js command.

my application does not use ports like 8080 and others, because the same library allows me to establish a connection and with pm 2 I keep it always active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the start command to your `package.json` for launching your app with pm2, then with your bat file just direct it to run with `npm` or `yarn`, whatever your default package manager is

edit:

here is a sample of a script in bash, but the concept will be the same for batch

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## detect operating system machine so we can setup some environment variables
UNAME="$(uname -s)"
case "${UNAME}" in
    Linux*)     OS='linux';;
    Darwin*)    OS='mac';;
    CYGWIN*)    OS='cygwin';;
    MINGW*)     OS='mingw';;
    *)          OS="UNKNOWN:${UNAME}"
esac

## if OS is Ubuntu (IE Production Box) set the path of variables
if [ $OS == 'linux' ]
then
  YARN=/usr/bin/yarn
  PM2=/usr/bin/pm2
fi
## if OS is Mac (IE Development Box) set the path of variables
if [ $OS == 'mac' ]
then
  YARN=/usr/local/bin/yarn
  PM2=/usr/local/bin/pm2
fi

## run the app
cd /var/www/application || exit
$YARN run productionStart

$PM2 save

exit $?
```

here is the line of code for starting the app on mac/linux we use from our package.json

```json
"productionStart": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env=production",
```

for more information about starting your app with an ecosystem file with pm2, see the docs [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)

Comment: thanks for replying, I managed to add the ecosystem.config.js file to my package.json file and I managed to run it normally (from vsc), what is not clear to me is how to apply it to a bat or cmd file, I hope you can help me.